# Json: End of input at character 3 of

Tags: php, mysql, json

Another day another dollar, json still throwing exceptions..

The above error in title does not provide enough information to troubleshoot my code below, I have been going back and forth for a while now trying to just simply query mysql using IMEI variable.

PHP:

```
<?php

include 'config.php';

$con=mysql_connect("$servername", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$dbname")or die("cannot select DB");

if( isset($_POST["json"]) ) {
     $value = $_POST["json"]; 
     $decoded_value = json_decode($value);

    $sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE IMEI = '".$decoded_value->{'msg'}."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $json = array();

    if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $json['contact_info'][]=$row;
    }

    }

    echo json_encode($json); 

    //write to log.txt
    $f = fopen("log.txt", "w");
    fwrite($f, print_r($sql, true));
    fclose($f);  
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Output of log.txt

```
SELECT * from users WHERE IMEI = '000000000000000'
```

Error returned:

```
11-28 11:56:38.230: I/System.out(2377): Json Errororg.json.JSONException: End of input at character 3 of
```

Output of json:

```
    Array
(
    [contact_info] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [_id] => 1
            [IMEI] => 000000000000000
            [Name] => Kay
            [Number] => 0767777777
            [Username] => kman
            [Request] => 
            [Request_IMEI] => 
            [Request_Name] => 
            [Request_Number] => 
            [Request_Username] => 
            [Request_Result] => 
            [Status] => 
        )

        [1] => Array
        (
            [_id] => 5
            [IMEI] => 000000000000000
            [Name] => Kay
            [Number] => 0767777777
            [Username] => kman
            [Request] => 1
            [Request_IMEI] => 111111111111111
            [Request_Name] => John 
            [Request_Number] => 222
            [Request_Username] => jj
            [Request_Result] => PENDING
            [Status] => 
        )

        [2] => Array
        (
            [_id] => 6
            [IMEI] => 000000000000000
            [Name] => Kay
            [Number] => 0767777777
            [Username] => kman
            [Request] => 0
            [Request_IMEI] => 888888888888888
            [Request_Name] => Friendly
            [Request_Number] => 0121111111
            [Request_Username] => friendlyguy
            [Request_Result] => OK
            [Status] => ONLINE
        )

        [3] => Array
        (
            [_id] => 7
            [IMEI] => 000000000000000
            [Name] => Kay
            [Number] => 0767777777
            [Username] => kman
            [Request] => 0
            [Request_IMEI] => 161616161616166
            [Request_Name] => Cool
            [Request_Number] => 0122222222
            [Request_Username] => coolcat
            [Request_Result] => OK
            [Status] => OFFLINE
        )

        [4] => Array
        (
            [_id] => 8
            [IMEI] => 000000000000000
            [Name] => Kay
            [Number] => 0767777777
            [Username] => kman
            [Request] => 2
            [Request_IMEI] => 666666666666666
            [Request_Name] => Skeptic
            [Request_Number] => 0125555555
            [Request_Username] => SK
            [Request_Result] => Rejected
            [Status] => 
        )

        [5] => Array
        (
            [_id] => 9
            [IMEI] => 000000000000000
            [Name] => Kay
            [Number] => 0767777777
            [Username] => kman
            [Request] => 3
            [Request_IMEI] => 999999999999999
            [Request_Name] => Block
            [Request_Number] => 01299999999
            [Request_Username] => BL
            [Request_Result] => Blocked
            [Status] => 
        )

    )

)
```

Output of json_encode:

```
{"contact_info":[{"_id":"1","IMEI":"000000000000000","Name":"Kay","Number":"0767777777","Username":"kman","Request":"","Request_IMEI":"","Request_Name":"","Request_Number":"","Request_Username":"","Request_Result":"","Status":""},{"_id":"5","IMEI":"000000000000000","Name":"Kay","Number":"0767777777","Username":"kman","Request":"1","Request_IMEI":"111111111111111","Request_Name":"John ","Request_Number":"222","Request_Username":"jj","Request_Result":"PENDING","Status":""},{"_id":"6","IMEI":"000000000000000","Name":"Kay","Number":"0767777777","Username":"kman","Request":"0","Request_IMEI":"888888888888888","Request_Name":"Friendly","Request_Number":"0121111111","Request_Username":"friendlyguy","Request_Result":"OK","Status":"ONLINE"},{"_id":"7","IMEI":"000000000000000","Name":"Kay","Number":"0767777777","Username":"kman","Request":"0","Request_IMEI":"161616161616166","Request_Name":"Cool","Request_Number":"0122222222","Request_Username":"coolcat","Request_Result":"OK","Status":"OFFLINE"},{"_id":"8","IMEI":"000000000000000","Name":"Kay","Number":"0767777777","Username":"kman","Request":"2","Request_IMEI":"666666666666666","Request_Name":"Skeptic","Request_Number":"0125555555","Request_Username":"SK","Request_Result":"Rejected","Status":""},{"_id":"9","IMEI":"000000000000000","Name":"Kay","Number":"0767777777","Username":"kman","Request":"3","Request_IMEI":"999999999999999","Request_Name":"Block","Request_Number":"01299999999","Request_Username":"BL","Request_Result":"Blocked","Status":""}]}
```

Comment: can you `var_dump($joson)` ? otherwise nobody can help you... just guess your problem